# Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword

I have a dictionary that has a place name as a key and as the value it has several lists of words, eg, 1 entry looks like:

```
{'myPlaceName': [u'silly', u'i', u'wish!', u'lol', [u'the', u'lotto'], [, u'me', u'a', u'baby?'], [u'new', u'have', u'new', u'silly', u'new', u'today,', u'cant', u'tell', u'yet,', u'but', u'all', u'guesses', u'silly']]}
```

How can I join them all so I can get the common words associated with each place?
I would like my output to get silly and new as the common words for the dictionary.

Comment: Your list contains other list and is not enclosed properly .

Comment: give an example of the expected output. It's slightly unclear what you want.

Comment: The value you show for the dictionary entry is a list of standalone words and sublist of other words, the delimiters for doing this are syntactically incorrect, it does not match your written description. Aside from the bracket issue, which is wrong, your description or the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function takes a list of a list of words, and returns all words that are found in all the lists.
eg `get_common_words([['hi', 'hello'], ['bye', 'hi']])` returns `['hi']`

```
def get_common_words(places):
    common_words = []
    for word in places[0]:
        is_common = all(word in place for place in places[1:]) #check to see that this word is in all places
        if is_common:
            common_words.append(word)
    return common_words
```

or the giant one-liner:

```
get_common_words = lambda places: [word for word in places[0] if all(word in place for place in places[1:])]
```

or just go with one of the methods suggested in the comments of this answer.

Comment: `reduce(set.intersection, map(set, places))`

Comment: @J.F. I should have known there was a more concise way than what I posted. It is Python, after all...

Comment: `set.intersection(*map(set, places))` on Python 2.6 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

`print ', '.join(dictname['myPlaceName'])`

This will create a comma-separated list of all the entries in the list. Replace `dictname` with the name of your dict.

Answer (score 1):

If it s a list containing only words, use join.

```
>>> k = [u'silly', u'i', u'wish!', u'lol']
>>> " ".join(k)
u'silly i wish! lol'
>>>
```